# How to use reflection inside a static method

Tags: reflection, static, c#-4.0

Ive got a logging method:

```
    public static void WriteSimpleDebugTrace(string logFilePathArg, string messageArg)
    {

        StreamWriter writer;

        //Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%SystemDrive%") [will get to the c drive]
        if (EnumsAndConstants.EnableApplicationLogging)
        {
            writer = new StreamWriter(logFilePathArg, true);
            writer.Write("Time: " + DateTime.Now.ToString() + " Message: " + messageArg);
            writer.Write(Environment.NewLine);
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();
        }

    }
```

And I am trying to access this.GetType().Name inside it but im not allowed to. Is there anyway around this? I want to easily get the calling class name when this method is called without having to rewrite all calls to this method...

Comment: *What* type do you want exactly? You could do `typeof(DeclaringClass)` / `MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType`, but that would only give you the type of the *logger* class. If you want the type of the class that called this method, you could examine the call-stack, but this is fraught with problems (possible JIT inlining etc).

Answer (score 0):

As it's static there is no `this` instance. You'd usually pass the actual instance into to method to provide method data. I have a logging class which accepts a `Reflection.MethodInfo` instance to output. As you don't want to change the method signature, perhaps you'd have better luck using the StackTrace diagnostics class:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace%28VS.71%29.aspx

Get the previous Frame, then recover the calling method. The example pretty much says it all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `stackTrace.GetFrame(1).GetMethod()` to retrieve the calling method and from there the associated class name